# Auto timestamp and date in multiple columns

Tags: date, google-sheets, timestamp, multiple-columns

I have a Google sheet [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dFYWduydJACvxGT88u1yOvAmRsfsiYoCg6ySGP3XuwA/edit?usp=sharing) where upon cell entry in column B a timestamp is placed in a cell in column C and a date in a cell in column G.
Two scripts with New Date does not work. Date cell is not allowed to have Time so that script is:

```
function onEdit() {
var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
if( s.getName() == "Guests" ) { //checks that we're on Guests or not
var r = s.getActiveCell();
if( r.getColumn() == 2 ) { //checks that the cell being edited is in column B
var nextCell = r.offset(0,5);
if( nextCell.getValue() === '' ) //checks if the adjacent cell is empty or not?
nextCell.setValue(new Date(new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0))).setNumberFormat('dd/MM/yyyy');
}
}
}
```

This script runs fine but the timestamp script will not.

```
function onEdit() {
var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
if( s.getName() == "Guests" ) { //checks that we're on Guests or not
var r = s.getActiveCell();
if( r.getColumn() == 2 ) { //checks that the cell being edited is in column B
var nextCell = r.offset(0,1);
if( nextCell.getValue() === '' ) //checks if the adjacent cell is empty or not?
nextCell.setValue(new Date());
}
}
}
```

I'm a total loser with scripts.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Already solved it.

I used the Timestamp script since that had the Date. Formatted the cell to show only Time and for cell G - Date

I extracted this from the Time cell by using:

```
=TO_DATE(INT(C9))
```